# what should I install to use kinect in the environment of ros(electric) besides openni_kinect?

Tags: kinect, rviz, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,everybody! I got problem in using rviz to display the image from kinect.I installed openni_kinect to drive kinect, but once I run rviz to display PointCloud2 data, my computer crashed. How can I record the PointCloud2 data and display it on the rviz? Is there anything I should install besides openni_kinect?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11339/what-should-i-install-to-use-kinect-in-the-environment-of-ros(electric)-besides-openni_kinect?/) by [llqazs](https://answers.ros.org/users/1121/llqazs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-09-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-09-28**:
Pls give details on system configuration used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So this is really an issue with RVIZ then. Do you have an NVIDIA graphics card? Are restricted drivers installed? You might check here: http://ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0